# How to bind Arrays in angular between components?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components

### Problem

I have 2 child-components and 1 parent component. First child is a simple list of tasks, second is map with points that showing whole project(project have list of Tasks), i have lots of interactions with points on the map, and i need to bind array of tasks between components.

### Main Component

HTML:

```
<app-tasks-list [(TasksList)]="Project.Tasks"></app-tasks-list>
<app-map [project]="Project" (onAddTaskModalClose)="addTaskToList($event)"></app-map>
```

TS:
In Typescript file I only handle onAddTaskModalClose() event and getting project from http.

### First child Component (list)

```
export class TasksListComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() onTasksChange: EventEmitter<ProjectTask[]>;
  @Input()
  get TasksList() {
    return this.Tasks
  }

  set TasksList(TasksList: ProjectTask[]) {
    this.Tasks = TasksList;
    this.onTasksChange.emit(this.Tasks)
  }
  private Tasks: Array<ProjectTask> = [];
}
```

In HTML I'm using TasksList getter for displaying data, ProjectTask is a huge Model, and sometimes im only changing one of the values nested inside, which doesn't fire setter (but this is other next problem).

### Second Component (map)

This is pretty simple component. Map that illustrate whole project and all of his points, and also i can add task from this component.

So i need a solution for passing Project.Tasks to one component (task-list-component is using in couple of places in my app) and when i change values of those tasks there, I need to show this changes on map instantly. Is there any simple way for this?

Comment: So there is no way to do this without other service and Observables?

Comment: There are other ways - such as the `@Input` and `@Output` similar to what you have in your code or something like session storage. [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39325503/how-to-pass-data-between-two-components-in-angular-2) however from the use case you have describe I think that a Subject (Observable) would be the best option

Comment: Just FYI, `Output` is always an `EventEmitter`, and `EventEmitter` is a sub-type of `Subject`, which in turns implements `Observable` interface. So yeah it's gonna be hard to find a solution without the use of `Observable`.