# Angular6 Data from Input to other component

Tags: html, angular, angular6

I have a component, which writes: Hello Angular6
**app.component.html:**

`<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>`

**app.component.ts:**

```
 import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular 6';
}
```

Task is, to make a new component, called `"Userchange"`

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-change',
  templateUrl: './userchange.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./userchange.component.css']
})
export class UserChangeComponent {
  @Input() change: string;  
}
```

There I have a button and a text type input, it should work like that: I write something to the input box, then I press the button, and the `'name'` in the app.component should be the given text.
can you please help me with that?

*I just begun learning Angular.*

Comment: If this is angular 6 then it should be tagged as angular and not angularjs. AngularJS is the pre2 library that is vastly different than modern angular. Should also update the title to reflect Angular 6 vs AngularJS

Comment: @scrappedcola thanks, done it

Comment: Have you read angular 6 tour of heroes tutorial?

Comment: I would suggest checkout the tutorial mentioned by firegloves and also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39325503/how-to-pass-data-between-two-components-in-angular-2, note angular 2+ work fundamentally the same it's only when you try to go back to pre2 that it's considered a different library.

Comment: @firegloves i have, i just don't get it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to Angular!
There are a few ways to do this. Here's one.

To see how it all fits together, you can view this code in StackBlitz [here.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v6za4c)

In userChange.component.html:

```
<input type="text" #myTextInput value="DefaultValue"/>
<button (click)="changeName(myTextInput.value)">Click me to change the name</button>
```

In userChange.component.ts:

```
nameValue: string;
@Output() nameChange = new EventEmitter();

changeName(val){
   this.name = val;
}

@Input()
  get name() {
    return this.nameValue;
  }

set name(val) {
   this.nameValue = val;
   this.nameChange.emit(this.nameValue);
}
```

App.Component.html will use two-way data binding, which means that your variable (in this case name) will be used as both a variable input and an output via the eventEmitter to signal back to the parent that name has changed, and to act accordingly:

```
<userChange [(name)]="name"></userChange>
Hi {{name}}
```

For further reference I'd reccomend going through Angular's tour of heroes and thoughtram's excellent post on [Two-way Data Binding.](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/10/13/two-way-data-binding-in-angular-2.html)

Answer (score 1):

I'm also learning angular :). Here is [another version](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-skhtcb), probably less neat then the previous answer.

Comment: Yours is probably a bit easier to understand though, as long as skick understands what NgModel does. In case he doesn't, the documentation is here: https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel