# How to pass data between angular components?

Tags: angular

I can't understand why I'm unable to pass data between two of the components in my Angular app. Here is what I have, but the child component is returning "undefined"

I am created an array of objects that simply take in a string, called profileFeedPosts, and trying to pass that to another component, again as an array of "Post" objects.

profile-feed is the parent, and public-feed is the child. Perhaps I'm missing something about the way parent/child components need to be structured in Angular?

Parent component:

```js
 import { Component} from '@angular/core';
 import { Post } from "../models/post.model"



 @Component({
      selector: 'app-profile-feed',
      templateUrl: './profile-feed.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./profile-feed.component.css']
    })
    export class ProfileFeedComponent  {

      postBody = null;

      profileFeedPosts: Post[] = [
        new Post("hello")
      ];

      showPostBody(){
        this.postBody = 1;
      }

      createPost(){
        this.postBody = null;
      }

      postSubmitted(post: string){
        const newPost = new Post(post);
        this.profileFeedPosts.push(newPost);
      }

      constructor() { }

      ngOnInit() {
      }

    }
```

Parent Component HTML:

```html
<div class="post-body" *ngIf="postBody">
  <input id="post" type="text" #userPost placeholder="What's up?">
  <button (click)="createPost(); 
postSubmitted(userPost.value);">Share</button>
</div>
<app-public-feed [childFeedPosts]="profileFeedPosts"></app-public- 
feed>
```

Child Component:

```js
    import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
    import { Post } from '../models/post.model';


    @Component({
      selector: 'app-public-feed',
      templateUrl: './public-feed.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./public-feed.component.css']
    })

    export class PublicFeedComponent {

      @Input() childFeedPosts: Post[];




      constructor() { }

      ngOnInit() {
      }

    }

    console.log(this.childFeedPosts);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass data between two components in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39325503/how-to-pass-data-between-two-components-in-angular-2)

Comment: *the child component is returning "undefined"* what does that mean. What **method** is returning undefined? How can the code even compile given that the last line is not part of any method of the PublicFeedComponent class?

Comment: Jack, it would be really helpful if you can provide sample code on stackblitz.com.

Answer (score 3):

You have placed the `console.log` outside the component class, into the global scope, where `this.childFeedPosts` does not exist.

Try moving the `console.log` inside the `PublicFeedComponent.ngOnInit` method.

Comment: Man, thank you so much. I was going insane thinking everything was formatted correctly. I feel very silly now.