# How to pass data between 2 component in angular

Tags: angular

I want to send the data when im navigating to page . How can i see the data in second page.

Example.

```
    this.router.navigate(['/dashboard/home', {company_id: '659'}]);
```

I m passing company_id to homeComponent. how can i console Company_id in homecomponent Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass data between two components in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39325503/how-to-pass-data-between-two-components-in-angular-2)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly,set your `homeComponent` constructor

```
constructor(
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute
    .....
) { }
```

and get params on `ngOnInit` function

```
ngOnInit(){
 this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(
    params=> {
           const company_id = params['company_id'];
           console.log(company_id);
});
```

Comment: how can i console the value of company_id ?