# Creating a component to access different object values

Tags: angular, angular6

I need to create reusable component for drop down control for which i will be passing different objects and will display properties based on the object i am sending. Is it feasible in angular?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass data between two components in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39325503/how-to-pass-data-between-two-components-in-angular-2)

Comment: Nope. I need to create a common component to show drop down control. to populate value in this, i need to pass different object and need to get property values. So i am asking is there any way to reuse to common component to populate values in drop down from different objects...

Answer (score 0):

Yes it feasible using @Input and @Output decorations in Angular 6.

Refer: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: For me, i need to populate data from different object - properties.