# Angular 8 how to pass data between three components

Tags: angular

I need to pass data from grandparent -> parent -> child component.

This is the grandparent html

```
<p>
Grant
<app-parent [child]="child" [other]="other"></app-parent>
</p>
```

Gratnt.ts

```
other = [{'name': 'abcd', age: 21},{'name': 'pqrs', age: 22}];    
child = [];
    getData() {
    this.service().subscribe((res)=>{
    this.child = res; })
```

Parent html

```
<p>
Parent
<app-table [child]="newKid" [other]="newKid2"></app-table>
</p>
```

parent.ts

```
@Input child = [];
@Input other = [];
newKid = [];
newKid2 = [];
process() {
//Process Data
this.newKid = this.child;
this.newKid2 = this.other;
}
```

table.html

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr *ngFor="let item of child"></tr>
</thead>
<tbody><tr *ngFor="let item of other"></tr></tbody>
</table>
```

table.ts

```
@Input child = [];
@Input other = [];
```

My Question is how to transfer data to nested chain component.?

Comment: Please take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39325503/how-to-pass-data-between-two-components-in-angular-2

Comment: So you need to need to know how to pass data between three child components or do you want to know how to pass data from grandparent -> parent -> child?

Comment: Rather than creating service we are not able to pass the data to chain components.

Comment: Pass data from grandparent -> parent -> child

Comment: @Input() doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of `Subject`which is available in `rxjs`

**GrandParent.component.html**

```
<app-parent [parentSubject]="parentSubject.asObservable()"></app-parent>
```

**GrandParent.component.ts**

```
@Output() parentSubject: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>(true);
clickEvent(){
   this.parentSubject.next(true);
}
```

**Parent.Component.html**

```
<app-child [childSubject]="childSubject.asObservable()"></app-child>
```

**Parent.Component.ts**

```
@Input() parentsubject: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>(true);
@Output() childSubject: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>(true);

this.parentsubject.subscribe(res=> {
   this.childSubject.next(res);
})
```

**Child.Component.html**

```
<div></div>
```

**Child.Component.ts**

```
@Input() childSubject: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();
this.childSubject.subscribe(res => {
  Console.log(res);
});
```

Hope this helps. Cheers :)