# how to share data between component with @input/@output in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to share data between component with use @Input or @output because I'm just need to share in back-end don't need to display

Comment: With or without? Make sure that the title and the description match.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass data between two components in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39325503/how-to-pass-data-between-two-components-in-angular-2)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass data between `components` without `@input @output` so you can user service.

In `data.service.ts` you can do like this

```
sharedData : any;

setData(data){
  this.sharedData = data;
}
getData(){
  return this.sharedData
}
```

And in your `parent.component.ts` you can set data like this

```
constructor(private _dataService : DataService){}

this._dataService.setData(dataToBeShared);
```

And in your `child.component.ts` you can get that data like this

```
constructor(private _dataService : DataService){}

console.log(this._dataService.getData())
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass data between components without @input @output so you can use service.

In share.service.ts you can do like this

```
search: EventEmitter < boolean > = new EventEmitter();
toggle(value:any) {
    this.search.emit(value);
}
```

Component where you want data:

```
ngOnInit() {    
  this.service.search.subscribe(value => {
       //some code here
  }
}
```

Component from where you are sharing data:

```
submit():void{
  this.service.toggle(somedata);
}
```