# I want to share form(textarea) value in angular

Tags: angular

I want to share form value in angular.

There is a FormGroup defined in main-component.
This is used in aaa/bbb-component.

I want to reflect the contents entered in the textarea of aaa-component to the textarea of bbb-component. Is there any method?

---

Source code is available on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/github/otera/FormBind/tree/2adff084fab5329b7bdcaf31041b4c3cec914987).

Angular: 8.2.14

Comment: Basically you want to share data between components, this has been already [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53844631/11719787), If your question is different from this, please explain what you have tried and post the source code here, BTW the link you have provided is dead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@otera I'm not sure what you need. But change the Textarea HTML to the desired output.

Note - Add value `[value]="item.value"` tag in both aaa/bbb-component HTML files.

```html
<textarea [formControlName]="i" rows="5" [value]="item.value"></textarea>
```

Comment: This was what I wanted to do.  
Thank you.