# Pass a value of text fields from one component to another component in angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-services, angular-components

I am getting value from document.getElementByid from text field. 
I want to transfer the value got from getElementByid to other component. Any one can guide me how to do that.

Example 
component A:
get value using a=document.getElementByid
pass this value to 
Component B:
receive Value a from componentA.
Thanks.

Comment: Please check documentation on component interaction https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass data between two components in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39325503/how-to-pass-data-between-two-components-in-angular-2)

Answer (score 1):

If the other component is a child of the current component, you can listen to the input Event and update the value in the other component accordingly.

If the other component is not a child of the current component, you can use a singleton-service to pass the value to another component.

See https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tcgwkv for an example to both approaches.

Typing anything into the Main Component text box will update the values for both other components.

Comment: i want to communicate on the base of component level not with parent child relation.

Comment: For Communication between components that are not in a parent child relation you can use a singleton-service (as shown in the stackblitz).