# Pass data between 2 components in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ag-grid, pass-data

I'm trying to pass data from my ag-Grid to a form in a new component by clicking on the row.
I could get the data from the row by clicking on the cell via **onCellClicked** . But i don't know how to pass it to my other component now.
here is my 2 interfaces :
[image: Ag-Grid]

[image: Form]

and here is my code :
**ag-Grid.ts :**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Grid, GridApi } from 'ag-grid-community';
import { AgGridAngular } from 'ag-grid-angular';
import { DealsService } from '../services/deals.service';


import * as moment from 'moment';
import { RouterLinkRendererComponent } from '../router-link-renderer/router-link-renderer.component';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-deals',
  templateUrl: './deals.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./deals.component.scss']
})
export class DealsComponent implements OnInit {
  showNav = true;

  private gridApi;
  gridOptions = {
    rowHeight :90,
    headerHeight:60,

    defaultColDef: {
      sortable: true
  },
  }
  columnDefs = [


       {
      headerName: 'Deal',
      field:'DEALID',
      cellRendererFramework: RouterLinkRendererComponent,
      cellRendererParams: {
        inRouterLink: '/Repo'
      },
      width:300,
      resizable:true,
      onCellClicked: this.makeCellClicked.bind(this),
      filter: 'agNumberColumnFilter',


       },
       {
        headerName:'Block',
        field:'BLOCKID',
        width:200,
        resizable:true,
        filter: 'agNumberColumnFilter',
        columnGroupShow:'open',
      },
      ],
    },
   
];







rowData : any;

constructor(private service:DealsService) {}

onGridReady(params) {
  this.gridApi = params.api; 
}

getDropDownlist(){
  this.service.getDealsList().subscribe(data => this.rowData = data);

  }



  makeCellClicked(event) {
    console.log(event.data);

  }




ngOnInit() {
this.service.getDealsList().subscribe(data => {
  this.rowData = data;
}); 

}
}
```

I'm blocked and i do really appreciate your help guys.
Thank you!

Comment: Your example code is huge! Try to minify it thinking to the people that will read you...

Comment: where is the other component , to which you want to pass the data ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass data between two components in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39325503/how-to-pass-data-between-two-components-in-angular-2)

Comment: Try this: https://therichpost.com/how-to-share-data-between-two-components-in-angular-9/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shared service was the right solution.
[How to pass data between two components in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39325503/how-to-pass-data-between-two-components-in-angular-2)

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the service class to fetch the data based on the id or index of data, so example you pass id as a param to new child component and run a ngOninit to fetch that data based on identifier

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.sub=this._Activatedroute.paramMap.subscribe(params => { 
      const id = params.get('id'); 
      let dealer=this.dealsService.getDealer(id);    
  });
```

I am creating getDealer() based on assumption you have a get single dealer return function in your service if not then just run `dealer.find(dealer => dealer.ID==id);`

And then on your method in parent route =>

```
makeCellClicked(event) {
this.router.navigate(['/dealer-details', event.id]);
}
```

Not sure if this answers your question on how to fetch and display that data row.