# transfer data between component to another component make data undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

i use service to transfer data between component from article

[How to pass data between two components in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39325503/how-to-pass-data-between-two-components-in-angular-2)

```
export class SendService {
  constructor(
    private router:Router,
  ) { }
  private data;
  setData(data){
    this.data = data;
  }
  getData(){
    let temp = this.data;
      this.clearData();
    console.log('result is ',temp);
    return temp;
  }
  clearData(){
    this.data = 0;
  }
```

sender component data value = 1 or 0

```
  sender(data){
    this.transfereService.setData(data);
  }
```

Received component

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.data= this.transfereService.getData();
  }
```

when change the page in html  by component user get access to some menu by data= 1

but the problem is when refresh the page, data value = undefined ; what should I do ?

Comment: Do you want to persist the data in your application even if browser window is closed or what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @FabianStrathaus i try to send value between component to use it ; the result value change by page example on person  has access to edit menu and use ngif(result==1 )but refresh make it undefined  i don't want achieve it like localstroage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see, once you reload the page everything will go. so the `data` variable will be `undefined`. in your service, you're declaring the `data` variable but not assigning anything to it. to avoid an `undefined` issue just initialize that variable just like below.

```js
export class SendService {
  constructor(
    private router:Router,
  ) { }
  private data = 0; //changed line
  setData(data){
    this.data = data;
  }
  getData(){
    let temp = this.data;
      this.clearData();
    console.log('result is ',temp);
    return temp;
  }
  clearData(){
    this.data = 0;
  }
```

here I'm providing a local storage concept example to achieve your solution. by using local storage you can have your values on reload too. this is just an example - [stackblitz for local storage example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-localstorage-ovzhxf?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: how can i get current data this show data =0 on refresh  any solution?

Comment: as I mentioned... once you reload the page... you will loose all data

Comment: no solution for that ? so i cant use service

Comment: the solution is that you need to store your data in DB or somewhere and get it from there.

Comment: localstorage, cookies, ngrx store... try these concepts

Comment: i have store in session storage already ; Can we store another object on session ? multiple  storage on session

Comment: Yes you can store... Just use different key Name